# Android back button after clear task and set new task

Tags: android

So I have three activities A, B, and C (A>B>C). Before I startactivity(C) in B, I clear task and set new task to make C become a new root. Everything works as expected. When user clicks the back button in C, they go back to the main screen, but when the user clicks the app again, it redirects them to A. My thought is that there is nothing in the stack, so it just shows the default activity? How can fix this? so that when user clicks on the app again, then it will show C activity?

Comment: The default activity *is* the A activity.  That's how you defined it in the manifest.  Starting a new task with a new activity does not make it the default.  When the user launches the app the second time, and there are no current tasks to resume, so it will start the same activity that would normally be used to launch the app.

Comment: So the only option for the user to go back C is to set the condition in A  to check if the user is logged in, then go to C ? or is there any other way I could implement this?

Comment: Not that I know of.  What you just said is what I would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which Activity is going to launch through clicking is defined in AndroidManifest.xml, see this [official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html#launching-activity)

If all you need is to stop user from going back to Activiy A and B, maybe you can just override the `onBackPressed()` and don't clear tasks. In this way you can still have user navigated to C when the icon is clicked.